# Unable to connect remote jmx server from tomcat mbean

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

To my environment:
- Java 1.5
- Tomcat 5.5

I am trying to access remote mbeans from my web-app instances running on different machines for some clustering purpose. In general I am trying to access the oher remote mbeans from within a mbean itself using a rmi stub wrapped in some kind of a jmx server class like this:

```
public class JMXConnect {

PrintStream   out=    null;
JMXServiceURL    target=    null;
JMXConnector    connector=    null;
MBeanServerConnection   remote=   null;


String   serviceURL  =  "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://"+this.host+":"+this.port+"/jmxrmi";

target   =   new   JMXServiceURL(serviceURL);

connector   =   JMXConnectorFactory.connect(target);

remote   =   connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

ObjectName bean    =    null;

bean   =   new   ObjectName("MbeanName");

Object    returnval   =    remote.getAttribute(bean,"TotalSessionCount");
```

the problem is that when i try to use this code outside the tomcat context it works fine but from wihin this mbean in tomcat it causes troubles:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]
```

[exec] at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:317)
[exec] at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)

I found the missing classes in tomcat/common/lib/naming-factory.jar . however I do not know where to include this right (tried several locaions) nor what this class is all about or what I am probably misunderstanding here. The purpose of all this is that I want to get some of my mbeans working with each other on different machines using rmi stubs.

1) How do I get around the error ?
2) Is this approach useful ?